# Ways to interpret groups of bytes in a curl result as other data types

Tags: c++, c, curl

I'm trying to write a program which will query a URL using curl and retrieve a string of bytes. The returned data than needs to be interpreted as various data types; an int followed by a sequence structures.

The curl write back function must have a prototype of:

```
size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
```

I've seen various examples where the returned data is stored in a buffer either as characters directly in memory or as a string object.

If I have a character array, then I know that I can interpret a portion of it as a structure with code like this:

```
struct mystruct {
    //define struct
};

char *buffer;
//push some data into the buffer
char *read_position;
read_position = buffer + 5;
test = (mystruct *)buffer;
```

I have two related questions. Firstly, is there a better way of using curl to retrieve binary data and pushing it into structures, rather than reading it directly into memory as characters. Secondly if reading into memory as a character buffer is the way to go, is my code above a sensible way to interpret the chunks of memory as different data types?

Comment: I see that you edited back in the `C` tag.  Please note there is no such language as "C/C++".

Comment: As I said in the edit, I'm not wedded to using either language and happy to consider solutions in either. I'm more familiar with C++ and was hoping there might be some useful abstractions, such as streams, which could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Things you need to consider when interpreting raw structures, especially over network:

- The size of your data types;
- The endianness of your data types;
- Struct padding.

You should only use data types in your structure that are the correct size regardless of what compiler is used.  That means for integers, you should use [types from <cstdint>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint).

As for the endianness, you need to know if the data will arrive as big-endian or little-endian.  I like to be explicit about it:

```
template< class T >
const char * ReadLittleEndian32( const char *buf, T & val )
{
    static_assert( sizeof(T) == 4 );
    val = T(buf[0]) | T(buf[1]) << 8 | T(buf[2]) << 16 | T(buf[3]) << 24;
    return buf + sizeof(T);
}

template< class T >
const char * ReadBigEndian32( const char *buf, T & val )
{
    static_assert( sizeof(T) == 4 );
    val = T(buf[0]) << 24 | T(buf[1]) << 16 | T(buf[2]) << 8 | T(buf[3]);
    return buf + sizeof(T);
}

//etc...
```

Finally, dealing with potential padding differences...  I've already been naturally tending towards a 'deserialise' approach where each value is read and translated explicitly.  The structure is no different:

```
struct Foo
{
    uint16_t a;
    int16_t  b;
    int32_t  c;

    const char * Read( const char * buf );
};

const char * Foo::Read( const char * buf )
{
    buf = ReadLittleEndian16( buf, a );
    buf = ReadLittleEndian16( buf, b );
    buf = ReadLittleEndian32( buf, c );
    return buf;
}
```

Notice the templating handles sign and other things in the data type, so that all we care about in the end is size.  Also remember that data types such as `float` and `double` already have inherent endianness and should not be translated -- they can be read verbatim:

```
const char * ReadDouble( const char * buf, double & val )
{
    val = *(double*)buf;
    return buf + sizeof(double);
}
```

Comment: I've upvoted your answer because its extremely helpful, but I haven't accepted it because it doesn't address the curl portion of my question. Also your answer shows that my snippet of code (copying memory directly) is dangerously naive and I think you should explicitly say that in your answer.

Comment: Fair enough.  The thing you should realise is that if you have custom binary data, CURL doesn't care.  It's just binary data.  You use whatever method CURL provides for handling that, and you read the data as _you_ see fit.  It's nothing to do with CURL at that point.  It comes down to common practise for dealing with binary data across a network, which I think I addressed already.  I am assuming that you're serialising this data yourself on the server end as well as deserialising at the client end.

Comment: I just feel that there is an inefficiency. curl calls a write back function and passes it a character pointer together with the number of bytes read, which must mean that the data is already in memory. Its seems an unnecessary step to simply copy this data from one portion of memory to another. I was wondering if there was a better way to deal with the data as curl returns it. Yes, I'm serialising with PHP at the remote end of the connection. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I don't have direct experience with integrating CURL in code, but I would suspect that it won't always provide the entire binary data in one callback.  It's more usual for I/O callbacks to have a fixed buffer size, and provide you with _some_ data up to that buffer size, returning the remainder of your data in successive callbacks.  In that case, your only option is to copy the data out somewhere, and this is absolutely a normal thing to do.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly how curl works, multiple call backs. I know that there are some object wrappers for the library and I was wondering if it would be possible to treat the returned data as a stream, letting the extraction operators fill different data types as required.